Unity is not moving relative to the player instead of the world no matter what I do
I decided I wanted to make a 3D game one day, and I made the camera look around and everything, but when I tried to make WASD movement, it didn't work.
I tried every tutorial, AI, and piece of code I could find, but nothing would work.
Basically the problem is that I am trying to move my player with the WASD keys, but no matter what I do it will always move relative to the world and not the player (in simpler terms: the player always moves on the entire scenes X or Z axis instead of the player object's X or Z axis)
Here is my Hierarchy:
Directional Light
Floor
Player (the GameObject I am trying to move (btw it is a capsule))
Camera (the player's camera, which is childed to the parent
Player object)
I really can't figure this out and I've looked everywhere, but I have absolutely no idea. Anything would be helpful. Thanks! (by the way I can provide any info needed)

Can you share your player controller script ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@jakubpodhaisky Hi, I just recently started making this game and I was working on the controls for movement (WASD) and I would like to help but I don't yet have a player controller script. I can provide the current movement code that is not working and the camera (look around the area script) script if needed.

Than provide that please see minimal reproducible example

would you please try this script. Remember you should have a character controller on your player object. Yet, you should provide more information like how you code it and how does it didn't work.
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5.0f;
    private CharacterController characterController;

    private void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); 
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        // Move in local space
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(horizontal, 0, vertical);
        movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement);
        characterController.Move(movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}


Thanks for the tip, I am a new stack overflow user so I don't know much about this. I will try that script.

First, check that your camera look script is also rotating the player body. If that's working but the player is still moving along the world axes, use transform.TransformDirection(), with the transform being the players body, in whatever code physically moves / applies force to the player. What this code will do is manipulate a vector3 to convert it from world axes to local axes.
Hope this helps :)

Sorry, but this didn't work, I tried to use that code and checked my camera script but it still had the same outcome. Thanks anyways!

I believe that means that your camera script is not rotating the player body then. If you don't have it already, have a line that goes something like body.rotation = quaternion.euler(0, camera.rotation.y,0). Double check the capitalisation but if that doesn't work, then I'm afraid I can't help you

Thanks, but this still didn't work, I had no errors but my player was still moving relative to the world and not on its own. Thanks for the help though!
